# How to move a span into another element in multiple instances?

Tags: jquery, each

I have multiple divs with this structure:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <p>things</p>
    <p>other things</p>
    <span class="read-less">read less</span>
</div>
<!-- duplicated several times -->
```

For each div, I want to move the `read-less` span within the last `<p>` tag, so the result would be:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <p>things</p>
    <p>other things <span class="read-less">read less</span></p>
</div>
```

For a single div, this can be achieved with:

```
$span=$(".read-less").clone();
$(".read-less").remove();
$("p:last-child").append($span);
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/4a78N/

**Question**

How could this same modification be achieved with multiple divs?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a better method, this seems to work:

```
$(".my_class").each(function() {
read_less = $(this).find(".read-less");
rl_clone = read_less.clone();
read_less.remove();
$(this).find("p:last-child").append(rl_clone);
});
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/4a78N/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a78N/3/)

```
$(".read-less").each(function(){
 $span=$(this).clone();
    $(this).prev('p').append($span)
    $(this).remove()
});
```